# Argument Error: Wrong Number of Arguments (2 for 1) when using parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

I've created parameters for an :image whitelist for a practice "pinboard" type application. Normally, the pin.rb would just call

```
attr_accessible :image
```

But Because it's Rails 4, I need to use strong parameters. As such, I've put them in the pins_controller.rb:

```
def pin_params
  params.require(:pin).permit(:description, :image)
end
```

But when I try to upload an image (using paperclip), I get this error:

```
ArgumentError in PinsController#create
wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)

Extracted source (around line #29):
27
28
29
30
31
32

  # POST /pins.json
  def create
    @pin = current_user.pins.new(pin_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @pin.save

Rails.root: /Users/michaeljdionne/Projects/Rails/omrails

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/pins_controller.rb:29:in `create'
Request

Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"awnx8EwrnA/ZoFIBe+ClL6wPbJ+sYnmTvwBCmzNmCHM=",
 "pin"=>{"image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fa4ab3796a8 @tempfile=#<File:/var/folders/39/00kqhhp14v9ddj0hrvg9_9bm0000gn/T/RackMultipart20130716-43150-1cflb9r>,
 @original_filename="IMG_0401.jpg",
 @content_type="image/jpeg",
 @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"pin[image]\"; filename=\"IMG_0401.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">,
 "description"=>"asd"},
 "commit"=>"Create Pin"}
```

I know that it has something to do with my parameters but I'm new to this and can't get it to work.

Answer (score 6):

Upgrading the paperclip to the most recent version should help:

```
gem "paperclip", "~> 3.5.1"
```

Comment: This worked for me! Wouldn't have thought to upgrade the gem for what seemed to be a params issue. Thanks!